# Doctrine : do not load related records

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

In order to improve performance of app, I would like to separate queries instead of using leftJoins. Then I have to create my own related Doctrine_Collection :

```
$user->Friends->add($current_friend);
```

But I don't want doctrine does a query when I try to access related (not loaded) Collection.

How I can do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in [this § about relation handling](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/improving-performance/en#improving-performance). Build a new friendship relation and save it instead of adding a friend to a user object.

Comment: I see what you mean but I don't want to save new Friends (its already exist in database), I want to re-create the object graph of users and friends by myself with multiple queries instead of only one.

Answer (score 0):

then I found this way (I should optimize this) :

```
$my_relation_collFriend = FriendTable::getInstance()->findByIdUser($user->id_user);

foreach($my_relation_collFriend as $friend)
{
   $collFriend = $user->get('Friends', false); //get the related collection without db query
   if(!$collFriend ) //unfornatly, It can be null 
   {
     $collFriend = new Doctrine_Collection::create('friend'); //create the collection
     $user->set('Friends', $collFriend, false); // define the related collection without db query
   }
   $collFriend->add($friend); //add the record to related collection
 }
```

With this example I know this is useless but with lot of joins and datas it becomes necessary